# The scrollbar is disappeared when I add an alert and cancel event by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm facing a problem is that when I use javascript to add an alert message to the page which has already had the vertical scrollbar, the message is shown perfectly but the vertical scrollbar is disappeared. When the alert message is dismissed, the scrollbar cannot appear again. Actually I don't want scrollbar disappearing anytime. I'm using bootstrap 3. Here is my code.

**HTML:**

```
... many HTML here ...
<div id="alertbox1"></div>
<div id="modal1">...stuff HTML here...</div>
... HTML here ...
```

**Script:**

```
$('#modal1').on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
    var ok = function_to_check_stuff_ok(); // ;)
    if (!ok){
        var myMessage = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'
        var htmlText  = '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">' +
                        '    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                        '    <p>' + myMessage + '</p>' +
                        '</div>';
        $('#alertbox1').html(htmlText);
        event.prevenDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: obviously there's nothing from with the code you posted, so you'll have to post the rest of it. better still put it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Hi. I've found that I called event.preventDefault() right after show the alert message inside `show.bs.modal` event. It make the scrollbar disapearred. I will update question and answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** The call of `event.prevenDefault()` did affect on showing of the modal as well as alert.

**Solution:** check and validate data and show alert message before calling open modal by manual (by calling `modal('show')`) instead of checking inside `show.bs.modal` event.